# List<T> caching, class iteration, count property

Tags: asp.net, episerver

Hy,

I have created a custom List, which tried to cache, but when getting back from cache, the cached object count is 0. Example code below:

```
List<CategoryEntry> categs = (List<CategoryEntry>)EPiServer.CacheManager.Get("test");

if(categs == null || categs.Count == 0)
{
    categs = ConstructCategories();
    EPiServer.CacheManager.Add("test", categs);
}

//Further down displaying the categories
```

UseCase:

First Pageload (after build) cache is empty, categs will be null,

Second Pageload cache will be, but will fail from get from there becouse `categs.Count will be 0` and reconstructs the cache again and again....

the CategoryEntry class:

```
 [serializable]
 public class CategoryEntry{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyPageId { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryEntryId { get; set; }
    public int Indent { get; set; }

}
```

The problem should be when saving the cache bc. it is saved as `object`, and when we get the cache we Cast to `List<CategoryEntry>`.

Also figured out if i do this with a `List<string>` instead of using `List<CategoryEntry>` 
then the caching works perfectly!.

Example with `List<string>` which is working:

```
List<string> test = (List<string>)EPiServer.CacheManager.Get("sindex");
if (test == null)
{
   test = new List<string>();

   test.Add("item1");
   test.Add("item2");
   test.Add("item3");
   test.Add("item4");
   test.Add("item5");

   EPiServer.CacheManager.Add("sindex", test);
}
else
{
   Response.Write("It works: elements  "+ test.Count);
}
```

Another Tryout was that i have cached a simple instance of `CategoryEntry` and that also works, the problem is when i try to save as `List<CategoryEntry>`

Any help Would be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: If the cache is empty (null) the cast won't work, you should probably use the "as" keyword when retrieving from the cache.

Are you running in a mirrored/load-balanced environment?

Comment: Have tried also as `EPiServer.CacheManager.Get("test") as List<CategoryEntry>` But the same result, right now i'm not in a load balanced environment

Comment: Please add `ConstructCategories()` logic - how you ensure it returns non-empty list?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use the standard runtime cache directly, i.e. HttpRuntime.Cache.Add/Get?